# Jpa is not flushing Transactional changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I use two-step registration. In the first step, I only require a username, password, and email. In the second step, I require a full name, bio, gender, etc. I have a `registerDetails` method for that. Inside `registerDetails`, there is `updateAppUser` method that updates the user with given information(full name, bio, gender, etc. ).  The `registerDetails` method is transactional because in the first step, I call for `updateAppUser` and in the second step I call for the `setDetailsRegistered` method. The `setDetailsRegistered` method only sets `isDetailsRegistered` boolean to true. I do that because I require the user to fill remaining information(full name, bio, gender, etc. ). Anyway, my problem is that when I return `AppUserResponse` after those two processes, I still get `isDetailsRegistered` as `false`, however, I used `setDetailsRegistered` method to set it as `true`. I understand that, because my method is transactional, it is still false when I call for the `AppUser` object because the transaction is not completed, yet. I want to close the transaction and after that retrieve the AppUser object from the database. I think I will get `isDetailsRegistered` as `true`. How can I achieve that? Those are my methods.

**registerDetails**

```
  @Transactional
    public AppUserResponse registerDetails(RegisterRequest registerRequest, UUID appUserId) {
        //fixme:first registerDetails returned false
        AppUser appUser = userDetailsService.findAppUserById(appUserId);

        if (appUser.isDetailsRegistered()) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException("Bu kullanıcının bilgileri zaten kayıtlı.");
        }

        AppUser mapped = appUserMapper.registerDetailsToAppUser(appUser,registerRequest);
        updateAppUser(mapped);
        setDetailsRegistered(appUserId);
        
        appUserRepository.flush(); //after updating and setting isdetailsRegistered flag as true, then flush changes.
        
        AppUser newAppUser = userDetailsService.findAppUserById(appUserId);
        return appUserMapper.appUserToResponse(newAppUser);
    }
```

**updateAppUser**

```
    public AppUser updateAppUser(AppUser appUser) {
        return appUserRepository.save(appUser);
    }
```

**setDetailsRegistered**

```
    public void setDetailsRegistered(UUID userId) {
        appUserRepository.setDetailsRegistered(userId);
        appUserRepository.flush();
    }
```

**jpa query for setDetailsRegistered**

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE AppUser a " +
            "SET a.isDetailsRegistered = TRUE WHERE a.appUserId = ?1")
    void setDetailsRegistered(UUID userId);
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. You are updating the databae and retrieving the cached entity. Why are you not just setting the value on the entity and just save the entity? What you are doing seems overly complex in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next code:

```
@Transactional
public AppUserResponse registerDetails(RegisterRequest registerRequest, UUID appUserId) {
    AppUser appUser = userDetailsService.findAppUserById(appUserId);

    if (appUser.isDetailsRegistered()) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException("Bu kullanıcının bilgileri zaten kayıtlı.");
    }
    appUser = appUserMapper.registerDetailsToAppUser(appUser,registerRequest);
    appUser = appUserRepository.save(appUser);
    //setDetailsRegistered(appUserId);
    appUser.setDetailsRegistered(true);//if you don't have this setter you can create it in the class AppUser
    appUser = appUserRepository.save(appUser);
    return appUserMapper.appUserToResponse(appUser);
}
```

Comment: That's a perfect way to do it :) With that solution, I don't need to go to db twice also, I don't need to use transaction. The code complexity decreased and the performance improved.